# React application perfomance. Server side rendering vs. Nginx

Tags: reactjs, nginx, serverside-javascript, server-side-rendering

Trying to understand which the most performant way of building React apps. I know that SSR rendering is fancy feature which gives you much better support of  SEO out of box, also it sends already generated html to client, so it has just show it and that is why it is more performant then simple schema of Node server + static files.
But, what about  Nginx? Every web developer knows that Nginx is fast, robust and configurable, so as a result Nginx is recomended for production use.

Have anybody compared these two approaches?